# ¿Cómo desactivar un job de Oracle luego de su ejecución?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql, jobs

tengo un job en Oracle que ejecuta un procedimiento almacenado y quiero desactivar el job una vez finalice su ejecución, pero si coloco el código para desactivarlo dentro del mismo procedimiento que llama, falla porque el job aún no ha acabado.

Este es el job que estoy creando:

```
    BEGIN 
   sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job( 
    job_name => 'JOB_EJECUCION_PRIMER_DIA', 
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
    job_action => 'BEGIN PKG_TAREAS_PROGRAMADAS.prc_ejecucion_mensual(1); END;', 
    start_date => TO_DATE('01-04-2022 22:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 
    enabled => false, 
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=22; BYMINUTE=30',
    comments => 'Job que se ejecuta el día cada mes'
   ); 
END;
/
```

El job yo lo activo respecto a otro proceso previo para que se ejecute ese mismo día en la noche.

Ahora bien, el procedimiento que llama sería algo así

```
PROCEDURE prc_ejecucion_mensual(p_numero_dia IN NUMBER) IS

    e_error_procedimiento EXCEPTION;

    BEGIN
    
    --EJECUCION DE PROCESO

    COMMIT;

    IF p_numero_dia = 1 THEN
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.DISABLE('JOB_EJECUCION_PRIMER_DIA');
    END IF;

    IF p_numero_dia = 2 THEN
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.DISABLE('JOB_EJECUCION_SEGUNDO_DIA');
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN e_error_procedimiento THEN
        BEGIN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Existe un Proceso activo');
        END;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        BEGIN
            dbms_output.put_line('Error: ' || sqlerrm);
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20102, sqlerrm);
        END;

    END prc_ejecucion_mensual;
```

El problema con  `DBMS_SCHEDULER.DISABLE('JOB_EJECUCION_PRIMER_DIA');`  es que el job todavía se está ejecutando entonces me lanza un error por esto mismo.

No se si haya una forma de desactivarlo luego de la ejecución. He encontrado que se le puede hacer drop, pero eso no es lo que necesito.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no seria lo mas recomendado que frenes un proceso de esa manera, lo mas recomendado es que optimices las consultas que tengas dentro de los procedimientos, para que el job no tarde tanto en ejecutarse.

Answer (score 0):

Podría fijar el intervalo de ejecución en una fecha muy, muy lejana en el futuro y mas bien desde el procedimiento prc_ejecucion_mensual, llamar el procedimiento

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB
```

para iniciar su ejecución de manera inmediata